# String not valid UTF-8 (BSON::InvalidStringEncoding) when saving a UTF8 compatible string to MongoDB through Mongoid ORM

Tags: ruby, utf-8, mongodb, mongoid, bson

I am importing data from a MySQL table into MongoDB using Mongoid for my ORM.  I am getting an error when trying to save an email address as a string.  The error is:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bson-1.2.4/lib/../lib/bson/bson_c.rb:24:in `serialize': String not valid UTF-8 (BSON::InvalidStringEncoding)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bson-1.2.4/lib/../lib/bson/bson_c.rb:24:in `serialize'
```

From my GUI - this is a screenshot of the table info.  You can see it's encoded in UTF8.

[image: table info]

Also from my GUI - this is a screen shot of the field in my MySQL table that I am importing

[image: what the data looks like in mysql GUI]

This is what happens when I grab the data from MySQL CLI.

[image: what the data looks like in mysql CLI]

And finally, when I inspect the data in my ruby object, I get something that looks like this:
[image: inspected ruby object]

I'm a bit confused here because regardless my table is in UTF-8 and that funky is apparently valid UTF-8 character as a double byte.  Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: It'd be most helpful if you could post a reproducible example to jira.mongodb.org. That way, we can test and make sure there's not a bug in the driver's UTF-8 check. It does use a standard UTF-8 validation library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this helper:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4527

It puts a method utf8? on the String. So you can grab the String from mysql and see if it is utf8:

```
my_string.utf8?
```

If is not, then you can try change the encoding of your String using other methods like:

```
my_string.asciify_utf8
my_string.latin1_to_utf8
my_string.cp1252_to_utf8
my_string.utf16le_to_utf8
```

Maybe this String is saved on mysql in one of these encodings.

Comment: converting from latin1 to utf8 worked.  weird how my database is encoded (or claims to be) in utf8 though.  thanks a ton!